# Excel file reader/writer libraries for PHP issue for Date

Tags: php, date, xls

I am using simplexlsx.class.php to read xlsx file type. It's giving problems when the file contain date field in the excel file.

here is my coding

```
require_once "simplexlsx.class.php";
$xlsx = new SimpleXLSX( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] );
list($cols,) = $xlsx->dimension();
     foreach( $xlsx->rows() as $k => $r) {
   echo $r[42];
 }
```

when  i echo this echo $r[41]; it print 41378...
date format is m/d/Y and i want to change it to Y-m-d which not working.

```
date("Y-m-d", strtotime($r[42]));
```

Comment: example of XML would be helpful.

Comment: XML?what does this mean?i have date let say 3/4/2013 in excel file,i want to read it..that it

Comment: No it isn't that in the Excel file, it just __looks__ like that... change the `number format` in MS EXcel to from `date` to `number` and you'll see what it really is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're retrieving the Excel timestamp, which is based on number of days since a 1st Jan 1900 or 1st Jan 1904 serialization.

You can use the following functions to convert that value to a unix timestamp (that you can then manipulate using PHP date functions) or to a PHP DateTime object:

```
function ExcelToPHP($dateValue = 0, $ExcelBaseDate = 1900) {
    if ($ExcelBaseDate == 1900) {
        $myExcelBaseDate = 25569;
        //    Adjust for the spurious 29-Feb-1900 (Day 60)
        if ($dateValue < 60) {
            --$myExcelBaseDate;
        }
    } else {
        $myExcelBaseDate = 24107;
    }

    // Perform conversion
    if ($dateValue >= 1) {
        $utcDays = $dateValue - $myExcelBaseDate;
        $returnValue = round($utcDays * 86400);
        if (($returnValue <= PHP_INT_MAX) && ($returnValue >= -PHP_INT_MAX)) {
            $returnValue = (integer) $returnValue;
        }
    } else {
        $hours = round($dateValue * 24);
        $mins = round($dateValue * 1440) - round($hours * 60);
        $secs = round($dateValue * 86400) - round($hours * 3600) - round($mins * 60);
        $returnValue = (integer) gmmktime($hours, $mins, $secs);
    }

    // Return
    return $returnValue;
}
```

Set $ExcelBaseDate as necessary to indicate the Excel base calendar that you're using: Windows 1900 or Mac 1904

and if you want a PHP DateTime object instead:

```
function ExcelToPHPObject($dateValue = 0, $ExcelBaseDate = 1900) {
    $dateTime = ExcelToPHP($dateValue, $ExcelBaseDate);
    $days = floor($dateTime / 86400);
    $time = round((($dateTime / 86400) - $days) * 86400);
    $hours = round($time / 3600);
    $minutes = round($time / 60) - ($hours * 60);
    $seconds = round($time) - ($hours * 3600) - ($minutes * 60);

    $dateObj = date_create('1-Jan-1970+'.$days.' days');
    $dateObj->setTime($hours,$minutes,$seconds);

    return $dateObj;
}
```

I'm surprised that SimpleXLSX doesn't have methods for handling this conversion, though dates aren't normally held as this serialized value in OfficeOpenXML format (xlsx) workbooks

Comment: i am using SimpleXLSX class as mentioned in question..now what i should do?

Comment: I've given you a solution: `echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime(ExcelToPHP($r[42])));` - what do you think the two functions I posted in my answer are for?

Comment: i used the first function,give me 1970-01-01

Comment: Sorry, should have been `echo date("Y-m-d", ExcelToPHP($r[42]));`

Comment: Wow you've saved my day!! Was going crazy trying to figure out how I've got this weird number, but the weirdest part is that in the same XLSX file one date was being imported without any problem but some other date was throwing the days since 1900 or some.. but well now it works, so Thanks A Lot!